# When will CoreNLP 4.1.0 be on Maven Repo?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Out of curiosity (and because I always want the latest awesomeness in your awesome code), when will the 4.1.0 version of CoreNLP be published to Maven?

(BTW, thank you for your amazing work. Can't be said often enough.)

Comment: Even if it will be there, I think you should not use it immediately, but use the stable version instead, for a while. I used to work on CoreNLP in 2018, when 3.9 was already in the Maven Repo, and still used 3.8, as it was stable.

Comment: I think we're going to try to do a 4.1.1 with some small fixes and just jump ahead to that on Maven Central...either way I'll try to get something up in the next 2 weeks!

Answer (score 0):

CoreNLP 4.2.0 is now available on Maven.